# Symfony merge multiple columns

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatables

i want to merge multiple columns in one column in Symfony, something like this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a group by? You will have to use the query builder of doctrine to do this. You can not do it by findBy or findOneBy on the repository. Check out the doctrine docs on query builder : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
SELECT date, SUM(hour) FROM your_table GROUP BY date
```

Result:

```
Date  | Hour
10.12 |   8
```